# EntityFramework Core 1.1.1 - Replacing old collection with new and overwriting values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following snippet of code which I have been using for several months to update a Data model of `Client` with values passed back via a ViewModel.

I am using LINQ to filter on the collection of Email CC values passed from the client, which is a List of strings, and create a new instance of the `EmailCC` object with the email address specified, this is then assigned to the clients EmailCCs which is a One to Many relational mapping. The correct behavior I'd expect is to break the relationship between the previously entered Email CC's and then use the newly entered values.

After updating to the latest version of EF Core, I am receiving the following exception when attempting to update, which I believe I understand is due to deleting and modifying the `EmailCCs` collection in the same context.

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'EmailCC' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

My EmailCC Primary Key column is Database Generated.

The Post method code is

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(
    [Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Email,EmailCc")] ClientEditViewModel clientEditViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(clientEditViewModel);

    Client client =
        _dbContext.Client.Include(p => p.EmailCCs).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == clientEditViewModel.Id);

    client.FirstName = clientEditViewModel.FirstName;
    client.LastName = clientEditViewModel.LastName;
    client.Email = clientEditViewModel.Email;
    client.EmailCCs =
        clientEditViewModel.EmailCc.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
            .Select(p => new EmailCC { Email = p }).ToList();

    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Edit), new { id = client.Id });
}
```

EmailCC class is

```
public class EmailCC
{
    [Column("ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Client Class:

```
public class Client
{
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmailCC> EmailCCs { get; set; }
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way, and if so, what is the correct way of replacing collections where I don't care about the values in that collection as long as they're overwritten with the new values?

Comment: Can you post the `EmailCC` class

Comment: @IvanStoev updated to include both `EmailCC` and `Client` classes

Comment: Your `EmailCC` PK column is **not** database generated. Probably should remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` or use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating and applying migration from your model generates the following SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE [EmailCCs] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] int,
    [Email] nvarchar(max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmailCCs] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmailCCs_Clients_ClientId] FOREIGN KEY ([ClientId]) REFERENCES [Clients] ([ID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

You can notice several problems here. The PK is not `IDENTITY`, hence is **not** database generated. You should remove the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` annotation or use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`.

The second issue is `ClientId` column is being nullable, and delete cascade being off (`ON DELETE NO ACTION`). In order to make replacing code working, you need to configure the relationship to be required with delete cascade.

Here is the fixed model:

```
public class EmailCC
{
    [Column("ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasMany(e => e.EmailCCs)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

which now creates a different command:

```
CREATE TABLE [EmailCCs] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ClientId] int NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmailCCs] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_EmailCCs_Clients_ClientId] FOREIGN KEY ([ClientId]) REFERENCES [Clients] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and more importantly, the code in question w.o any modification works as expected (no exception, old `EmailCCs` collection is replaced with the new values).

Comment: The `DatabaseGenerated` attribute was the problem, now resolved. Great info in this answer, thanks Ivan

Comment: You are welcome. But I would recommend checking the database table, because w/o the fluent config and cascade delete, I found that the old `EmailCC` records were not deleted, but stayed in database with `ClientId` column being set to `NULL`.

Comment: With the assignment method, it only breaks the relationship link between the EmailCC and the client. I'll manually update the DbSet and make use of `RemoveRange` for each record inside in the `EmailCc` collection - should mark the entity state as Deleted.